# Apache superset this port is closed

Tags: mysql, docker, port, apache-superset

I have mysql installed on Alma Linux 8 and I have installed Apache Superset on docker using their guide on dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset

[image]

I keep getting The port is closed. The IP is of the host machine where Superset on docker is installed. I have tried using `host.docker.internal` as well but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the **cx_Oracle** with this command `pip install cx_Oracle`
and then you when you try to initialize connection to the database you choose Oracle and you can fill in the connection string as follows `oracle://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>`.